# Наследование между классами во FreePascal и написание "гибких" классов

Tags: pascal, наследование, freepascal, lazarus

Есть родительский класс:

```
HomerMatrix = class
    public
      var
        rows, columns: integer;
  end;
```

И есть классы-потомки, для различных типов данных, такие как:

```
  HomerIntMatrix = class(HomerMatrix)
    private
      type
        Matrix = Array of Array of integer;
    public
      var
        Read: Matrix;
        def_cell: integer;
      constructor Create(h, w, def: integer);
  end;
```

Но такой код имеет несколько проблем:

- Громоздкий: Ещё не объявлено ни единого метода собственно работы с матрицами, но есть шесть(!) классов, пять из которых, фактически, различаются только типами данных в массиве.
- Плохо документируется: Вместо того, чтобы один раз дать описание
  полей `Read` и `def_cell`, выполняющих одну и ту же функцию во всех
  классах-потомках я вынужден документировать их в *каждом* из пяти.
- Все (или почти все) методы надо объявлять пятикратно, или
  использовать тип `variant`, жрущий память со скоростью пылесоса. Первый вариант - опять лишний код и пятикратное документирорвание.
- Для каждого типа матрицы свой класс и конструктор.

Получается, я как бы использую классы, а на деле не использую, так как от класса-родителя наследуются только два поля.

Что я хочу, в идеале:

- Все методы, кроме специфичных для отдельных типов данных (отрицание, для булевой матрицы, например) создаются один раз, в классе `HomerMatrix`.
- Аргументы функций и процедур, имеющие разный тип данных, в разных классах-потомках, переопределяются в них.
- Поведение функций и процедур `HomerMatrix` различается в зависимости от того, какой класс-потомок их вызвал.
- Конструктор `HomerMatrix` создаёт объект одного из классов-потомков, в зависимости от того, какой тип данных у аргумента `def`.

То есть, код

```
a := HomerMatrix.Create(5,5,0);
b := HomerMatrix.Create(5,5,'');
```

должен давать тот же результат, что и код

```
a := HomerIntMatrix.Create(5,5,0);
b := HomerStrMatrix.Create(5,5,'');
```

Подскажите, что из перечисленного возможно реализовать, и каким образом?

Comment: [Templates](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Templates)

Comment: @Grundy код, склееный из тысячи и одного шаблончика, не нужен. Я спрашиваю про программное решение. Более того, это "решает" только первую проблему, усугубляя остальные.

Comment: чем использование генериков не является программным? так же описывается общий класс и специфицируется. А уж говнокодом это будет или нет, зависит только от программиста:)

Comment: @Grundy так с тем же успехом можно просто растащить классы по разным юнитам, ещё и вставки писать не придётся. Но кода от этого меньше не станет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны дженереки.

```
TCustomMatrix<T> = class
private
  FMatrix: Array of Array of T;
  FDefCell: T;
public
  property Matrix: Array of Array of T read FMatrix;
  property DefCell: T read FDefCell;

  constructor Create<T>(Height, Width: Integer; Def: T);
end;
```

Используем:

```
var
  IntMatrix: TCustomMatrix<Integer>;
  StrMatrix: TCustomMatrix<string>;
...
IntMatrix := TCustomMatrix<Integer>.Create(3, 3, 0);
IntMatrix.Matrix[1,1] := 42;
StrMatrix := TCustomMatrix<string>.Create(3, 3, '');
StrMatrix.Matrix[2,2] := 'Превед, Медвед!';
```