# Не могу изменить размер динамического массива через свойство класса

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

У класса-родителя три свойства,

```
public
  property Rows: integer read GetNumRows write SetNumRows;
  property Columns: integer read GetNumColumns write SetNumColumns;
  property All: VarMatrix read IRead write IRead;
```

одно из которых переопределяется в классах-потомках:

```
property All: Matrix read MRead write MRead;
```

где тип `Matrix` - свой, для каждого потомка ([двумерный динамический массив с элементами разных типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502118/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE-freepascal-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

Есть две функции, возвращающие длину и ширину матрицы и две процедуры, наоборот, их задающие:

```
function HomerMatrix.GetNumRows:integer;
begin
  GetNumRows := length(All);
end;

function HomerMatrix.GetNumColumns:integer;
begin
  GetNumColumns := length(All[0]);
end;

procedure HomerMatrix.SetNumRows(NumRows:integer);
begin
  SetLength(All, NumRows); //На эту строку ругается компилятор
end;

procedure HomerMatrix.SetNumColumns(NumColumns:integer);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Rows-1 do SetLength(All[i], NumColumns);
end;
```

Всё это безобразие вызывается из класса потомка так (для целочисленной матрицы):

```
constructor HomerIntMatrix.Create(h, w, def: integer);
begin
  Rows := h;
  Columns := w;
  DefCell := def;
end;
```

Прочитать длину массива-поля по свойству получается, задать длину массивов второго уровня - тоже, но `SetNumRows` выдаёт ошибку:

> Can't take the address of constant expressions

Если обратиться напрямую к полю

```
SetLength(IRead, NumRows);
```

ошибки нет, но мне нужно обратиться именно к свойству, чтобы работало переопределение.

[Полный код двух классов](http://pastebin.com/v6w75Vp6). Собственно, почему возникает эта ошибка, и как её обойти?

Comment: `"SetLength(All, IRead);`" ??? Может `SetLength(IRead, NumRows);`?

Comment: @Igor, да, конечно. Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Для компилятора, обращение к свойству равнозначно вызову функции getter'а, даже если это свойство опирается напрямую на поле класса. Использование результата вызова функции в качества var параметра в SetLength - бессмысленно.
2. Однако, Ваша фраза "одно из которых переопределяется в классах-потомках", вызывает подозрения в правомерности Вашего дизайна вообще. Если `IRead` является членом класса базового `HomerMatrix`, и, соответственно свойство `property All: VarMatrix ...` тоже принадлежит классу `HomerMatrix`, тот факт, что у наследника есть свойство `property All: Matrix ...` никак на базовый класс не повлияет, и все операции с `All` в коде базового класса будут выпонены для свойства `property All: VarMatrix ...`, а `MRead` никак затронуто не будет.
3. Надо разбираться с наследованием, виртуальностью и полиморфизмом, но для этого кода в вопросе - недостаточно.

Посмотрел код. Как я и думал - все неправильно. Ни компилироваться, ни работать (если Вы каким-то чудом его откомпилируете) это не будет. Перечитайте пункт 2 выше. (При чем здесь вообще конструктор, который Вы упоминаете в комментарии?)

Далее.

Вы объявляете тип `VarMatrix` как `private`, а свойство `property All: VarMatrix ...` как `public`. Каким образом внешний код будет работать с этим свойством, каким типом оно будет представлено?

Класс `HomerIntMatrix` переписывает только один из пяти абстрактных методов родительского класса. Помнится, Delphi 7 еще позволял такие вещи (при некоторых условиях) - не знаю, как сейчас. Но создание объектов таких классов чревато большими неприятностями.

Будем продолжать?

Comment: Я там добавил сам вопрос) На половину оного вы как раз и ответили, да.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на Pastebin.

Comment: Компилируется оно, как раз, легко, но действительно не работает.


То есть, переопределение свойства будет работать только для функций и процедур дочернего класса? А переопределение самих функций и процедур? И в чём тогда глубокий смысл возможности переопределять?


Я полагал, что если тип используется только свойством или полем того же класса, то его можно убрать в приват, так как свойство/поле его увидит, а остальным и не надо? Я не прав?

Comment: Остальные абстрактные методы переписывают, по задумке, те классы-потомки, которые их используют. Траблы начались, когда я попытался превратить в свойство сам массив. При работе с массивом, как с полем дочернего класса, `Rows`, `Columns` и `DefCell` работали.

Comment: Мне трудно себе представить это "работали". Код базового класса понятия не имеет о свойстве `property All: Matrix ...` наследника и не может влиять на `MRead`. Но я чувствую, мои слова остаются гласом вопиющего в пустыне.

Comment: `MRead` (тогда `Read`) был видим, разумеется (старый код: http://pastebin.com/NYEhKT79). А вот типы у меня всю жизнь сидели в `protected` или `private` и не жаловались. Поля же, процедуры и функции, используемые только свойствами, прячут в `private` даже в примере (http://www.introligator.org/articles/1/29), лишь бы свойство было `public`.

Comment: "MRead (тогда Read) был видим" из переопределенных (`override`) функций класса наследника, а не из кода родителя

Comment: Ладно, остановимся пока на этом. Надо разбирать на отдельные вопросы.