# Вариативность функций во FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Первая ситуация: Есть класс, в котором объявлена процедура

```
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:integer);
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:real);
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:string);
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:char);
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:boolean);
```

Аналогичные конструкции можно видеть и в родных подключаемых модулях Lazarus, например `fpjson`. При этом, как я понимаю, будет вызвана та подпрограмма, в аргументах которой указана переменная того же типа, что и переданная в вызове процедуры. Почему это работает, несмотря на отсутствие директивы `overload`? Когда эту директиву нужно использовать, а когда можно (или нужно) опустить?

Вторая ситуация: Процедуры объявлены в родительском классе

```
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:integer);dynamic;abstract;
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:real);dynamic;abstract;
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:string);dynamic;abstract;
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:char);dynamic;abstract;
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:boolean);dynamic;abstract;
```

И по одной переопределены в пяти классах потомках, с дерективой `override`. Будет ли работать такая конструкция и, если нет, то почему?

Comment: что значит _Будет ли работать такая конструкция_?

Comment: @Grundy будут ли методы корректно переопределяться в дочерних классах, не будет ли исключений, из-за того, что переопределены не все, какие ещё есть подводные камни?

Comment: Только что попробовал, будет `Warning: Constructing a class "B" with abstract method "SetDefaultValue"`, то есть, он будет работать запустится, но если будет вызов не переопределенной функции то будет `Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got "Single", expected "LongInt"` - ошибка компиляции

Comment: @Grundy, ну, что вызов не определённой функции приведёт к ошибке, ещё при компиляции, - это и ёжику понятно. Просто, меня тут(http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502274/14756) пытались убедить, что так делать **вообще** нельзя, но не соизволили объяснить, почему.

Comment: "приведёт к ошибке, ещё при компиляции, - это и ёжику понятно" - я - тот ежик, которому это не понятно

Comment: и да - повторю еще раз - так делать нельзя. Так делать - создавать себе проблемы на будущее. С другой стороны - job security and all that.

Comment: @Igor если вам есть, что написать по делу - пишите. Я задаю вопросы, чтобы получать ответы, а не спорить с вами на отвлечённые темы.

Comment: @Igor в последний раз спрашиваю: **Почему?** Меня интересует развёрнутое обоснование, с примерами кода, а не "умные мысли", высказанные общими фразами. Таких ответов я и сам могу давать 150 в час и все бесполезные.

Comment: @Risto, обоснование, что java и C# в такой ситуации по-разному выбирают метод, достаточное?

Comment: @Qwertiy такое обоснование было бы отмечено тревогой "Не является ответом". Посмотрите на метки и поймёте, почему.

Comment: @Risto, комментарий был отмечен, что не является ответом? Ну как бы если бы он являлся, его надо было бы в ответы и постить. А идея была в том, что переопределение части методов - идея плохая хотя бы потому, что делает принципы работы кода неочевидными. Читая код уже нельзя понять, какой метод вызывается, если ты не знаешь этот момент именно для этого языка.

Comment: @Qwertiy был бы, если бы был ответом. Однако, в более подробном варианте как один из возможных ответов уже подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > Почему это работает, несмотря на отсутствие директивы `overload`? Когда эту директиву нужно использовать, а когда можно (или нужно) опустить?

Как нам [сообщает](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu80.html) документация FreePascal (здесь и далее перевод мой, а ссылки [отсюда](http://www.freepascal.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10989), в квадратных скобках спорные участки перевода):

> Директива `overload` уведомляет компилятор, что эта функция перегружена. Главным образом, в целях обеспечения совместимости с Delphi, все функции и процедуры во FreePascal могут быть перегружены без использования данной директивы.

Однако, это не означает, что директива `overload` не используется. Другой раздел той же документации [сообщает](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse92.html) следующее:

> До версии компилятора 1.9 все [объявления] перегруженной функции должны были находиться в одном модуле. Сейчас компилятор продолжает поиск соответствия в других модулях, если не нашёл его в текущем, а функция имеет директиву `overload`.

То есть, директиву `overload` необходимо использовать только для функций, объявленных в разных модулях вашей программы.

- > Будет ли работать такая конструкция и, если нет, то почему?

Да, будет.

Однако, **не следует** использовать подобные конструкции, кроме случаев, когда абстрактные методы объявлены в *мета-классах*, то есть классах, единственное предназначение которых - хранить поля, свойства и методы, общие для всех классов-потомков мета-класса. Проще говоря, мета-класс - это класс, который никогда не заявляется как тип переменной и экземпляры которого никогда не будут создаваться.

```
var
  Meta: TMyMetaClass; //Так с мета-классами делать нельзя.

begin
  Meta := TMyMetaClass.Create; //И так тоже.
end.
```

Нарушение этого правила однажды закончится для вас страшным геморроем и неуловимыми, как ковбой Джо, ошибками, и вот почему (спасибо [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) за [разъяснения](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28352426#28352426)):

Предположим, мы объявили родительский мета-класс `A`

```
Type  
  A = Class  
  public
    val: integer;
    vals: string;
  public
    procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:integer);virtual;abstract;
    procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:string);virtual;abstract;
  end;
```

И два его класса-потомка, `B` и `C`

```
B = Class(A)
  public
    procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:integer);override;
end;
C = Class(A)
  public
    procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:string);override;
end;
```

Описали наши два метода

```
procedure  B.SetDefaultValue(DefValue:integer);
begin
  val := DefValue;
end;

procedure  C.SetDefaultValue(DefValue:string);
begin
  vals := DefValue;
end;
```

А затем решили: *"А зачем нам объявлять переменные двух разных типов, когда есть наследование?"* И написали...

```
var
  bb, cc: A;
```

...получив на свою голову кучу проблем. Потому что такой код:

```
begin 
  bb := B.Create;
  bb.SetDefaultValue(10);
  cc := C.Create;
  cc.SetDefaultValue(10);  
end.
```

Великолепно скомпилируется, чтобы, затем, вызвать ошибку выполнения. Что произошло? Сейчас, на маленьком коде-примере, это понять легко, но словив такую ошибку в многомодульном приложении на три тысячи строк вы рискуете искать её часами, без гарантии, что вообще найдёте. Следите за руками: Мы создали экземпляр класса `С`

```
cc := C.Create;
```

В котором, ранее, переопределили один метод

```
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:string);override;
```

Принимающий, в качестве аргумента, переменную типа `string`. А затем вызвали метод

```
cc.SetDefaultValue(10);
```

Передав ему аргумент типа `integer`. *"Но это же должно вызвать ошибку компилятора, почему, тогда программа успешно запустилась?"*, - спросите вы. Неверно, компилятор не видит в вашем коде ошибки, потому что, формально, её там **нет**. Напомнить, какого типа переменная `cc`?

```
cc: A;
```

А у класса `A` есть метод:

```
procedure SetDefaultValue(DefValue:integer);virtual;abstract;
```

К которому вы и обращаетесь. Но этот метод - абстрактный, он является лишь указанием для программы искать в области видимости экземпляра класса такой же метод с директивой `override`, которого она не находит, так как он определён только в классе `B`, но не `C`, о чём, при компиляции, вас **предупредил** Lazarus:

> Warning: Constructing a class "С" with abstract method "SetDefaultValue"

Что и вызывает ошибку выполнения. В то же время, такой код:

```
var
  bb: B;
  cc: C;

begin 
  bb := B.Create;
  bb.SetDefaultValue(10);
  cc := C.Create;
  cc.SetDefaultValue(10);  
end.
```

Просто вызовет ошибку компиляции на предпоследней строке, которую всегда легко найти и устранить.

**Примечание для внимательных читателей:** директива `dynamic` семантически эквивалентна `virtual`. Первая оптимизирована для памяти, вторая - для скорости.

Comment: overload - перегружена, override - переопределена

Comment: @Qwertiy переписал, но звучит криво. Какой бы русский аналог подобрать, чтоб без потери смысла?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, меня пару месяцев назад чей-то виртуал подловил (вроде Stack'а), аж вопрос написал на Мете.

Comment: @VladD, вроде читал. Там ещё был вариант ему написать такой же ответ с одним исправлением)))

Answer (score 1):

Ваши пять функций `SetDefaultValue` объявлены абстрактными в базовом классе. Значит, работать код будет с наследниками, которые эти функции переписывают (`override`).

1. Если переменная, указывающая на наследника, объявлена своим собственным типом (типом наследника) и ее собственная версия `SetDefaultValue` непосредственно видна компилятору, в виртуальности нет ни необходимости, ни смысла. Компилятор вставит ее вызов напрямую. И если для данного типа наследника нужен только вариант с целым, то об остальных ему и знать не надо, и в базовом классе они не нужны.
2. Если переменная, указывающая на наследника, объявлена типом базового класса, как Вы собираетесь определять, какой из пяти вариантов `SetDefaultValue` можно, а какой - нельзя вызывать?

Comment: Ага, теперь туман рассеивается. Только стоило, тогда, спросить зачем я вообще объявил абстрактные процедуры в классе, у которого даже конструктора не было? А сделал я это для удобства документирования, а не потому, что это нужно в коде.

Comment: @Risto туман сгущается - при чем здесь конструктор?

Comment: Потому что отсутствие конструктора намекает на мета-класс, не? "А кто будет присваивать переменной тип мета-класса?", думал глупый Ристо. То есть, я вообще не предполагал что описанное в п. 2 возможно. А ваш колмментарий на эту тему был столь "подробен", что не помог этого понять.

Comment: @Risto - Отсутствие конструктора в Паскале ни на что не намекает. Он все равно есть, только пустой. У меня чувство, что Вы пытаетесь применить идеи (или руководствоваться идеями) из какой-то другой среды (языка).

Comment: Знаю, что есть. Но что-то мне сомнительно, что дефолтным конструктором часто пользуются.

Comment: @Risto - "Вам сомнительно" ошибочно. Если в классе нет полей, которые должны быть инициализированы в момент создания класса  и при создании класса ему не передаются параметры - конструктор не нужен.

Comment: В большинстве случаев, там, тогда, и класс не нужен. Хватит записи.

Comment: @Risto Предлагаю прекратить препираться.