# Необязательные параметры функций и процедур FreePascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus

В продолжении [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502429/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE-freepascal?rq=1).

Есть процедура, с необязательным параметром:

```
procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string; rotate: boolean=false);
```

Которую, также, можно объявить, так:

```
procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string);overload;
procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string; rotate: boolean);overload;
```

Второй способ, очевидно, потребует написания большего количества кода, но он предусмотрен. В каких случаях его применяют и почему? Есть ли принципиальная разница между этими двумя способами?

Бонусный вопрос: может ли процедура из второго кода вызвать одноимённую процедуру, вот так?

```
procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string; rotate: boolean);
begin
  LoadCustomMap(height, width, map_type);
  // Какой-то код, специфичный для boolean=true
end;
```

Comment: сама себя? - это разные функции

Comment: @Igor, исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Есть ли принципиальная разница между этими двумя способами?***

В данном случае нет. Если бы методы были, например, такими:

```
function StrToInt(Str: string; DefaultValue: Integer = 0): Integer;
```

и

```
function StrToInt(Str: string): Integer; overload;
function StrToInt(Str: string; DefaultValue: Integer): Integer; overload;
```

то разница, очевидно, была бы в реализации. В первом случае функция всегда возвращает результат, не зависимо от значений аргументов. Во втором случае, первая функция может сгенерировать исключение, а вторая всегда вернет результат, причем, значение по умолчанию *придётся явно указать* при вызове.

***Может ли процедура из второго кода вызвать одноимённую процедуру, вот так?***

Может. Почему нет? Такой вариант вполне допустим.

```
function StrToInt(Str: string; DefaultValue: Integer): Integer;
begin
  try
    Result := StrToInt(Str); // вызов первого варианта функции
  except
  // не помню какое конкретно там будет исключение, правильно указывать конкретные 
  // типы исключений, а не общий - Exception
    on E: Exception do
     Result := DefaultValue;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "Во втором случае, первая функция может сгенерировать исключение, а вторая всегда вернет результат" это утверждение верно только для контракта именно этой процедуры. В общем такого поведения нет.

Comment: Именно по этому я и написал в самом начале "*Если бы методы были, например, такими:*"

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string; rotate: boolean=false);

procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string); overload;
procedure LoadCustomMap(height, width: integer; map_type: string; rotate: boolean); overload;
```

Заметьте, что эти варианты не тождественны.

- В первом и последнем случае идет явное определение поведения `rotate` (поворачивать или нет).
- Третий вариант явно требует указания аргумента.
- Во втором же варианте, явно объявлено, что поворот не предусмотрен.

Все это может отражаться в структуре кода процедуры, например исключением блоков кода отвечающих за обработку этого параметра. Для булевых аргументов это может быть не так заметно, как для других типов.

Например:

```
AddItem(обязательный параметр true) // добавить и сделать что-то одно
AddItem(обязательный параметр false) // добавить и сделать что-то другое
AddItem(необязательный параметр) // поведение по умолчанию (добавить и сделать что-то другое)
AddItem(без параметра) // просто добавить пустышку
```